# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://abc.mydomain.org/data/todo.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios

I want to use /data/todo.js file in my reactjs component. I have used axios http request to get this data in my react component i.e.,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class TodoList extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        var config = {
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8080/",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
            }
        };
        axios.get('http://abc.mydomain.org/data/todo.js', config)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="todo-list"></div>
        );
    }
}

export default TodoList;
```

It gives an error
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://abc.mydomain.org/data/todo.js. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Access control header needs to be on the backend.

Comment: Allow CORS in your backend server

Comment: There is no backend server yet.

Comment: I have simply uploaded the todo.js file on the server.

Comment: If it is a js file I dont see why you want to load it using axios? Does the file contain data or code?

Comment: #Mohit Mutha it is just a data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a cross-origin HTTP request from you application, which is by default blocked by the browser.

To access the resource, Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)  should be enabled at the application you are trying to access (In your case http://abc.mydomain.org)

> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests
>   initiated from within scripts. For example, XMLHttpRequest and the
>   Fetch API follow the same-origin policy. This means that a web
>   application using those APIs can only request HTTP resources from the
>   same domain the application was loaded from unless CORS headers are
>   used.

You can check more on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: I'm confused totally what to do. Can you add some code to explain as well my code requirement.

Comment: Do you have control on the doman  http://abc.mydomain.org. Are you the owner? I mean do you own the application or its a third party application?

Comment: I have only ftp access for this domain.

Comment: CORS can be enabled at application level or at the web server level. You can google to find more details specific to the technology for example "How to enable CORS' for ASP.NET or PHP